# join on foreign key with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

i am a hibernate-beginner and have a problem when trying to join 2 tables with hibernate. What i am trying to do is get the list of products a certain store has depending on the store id, but what i am getting is the list of all available products in the database listed under every store.

Here's the code for `Product.java` :

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "products")
public class Product implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1001086120280322279L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "product_id")
private int product_id;

@Column(name = "product_name", unique=true)
private String product_name;

@JoinColumn(name = "store", referencedColumnName="store_id")
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Store store;
```

etc..

and here's the code for `Store.java` :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stores")
public class Store implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4497252090404342019L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "store_id")
private int store_id;

@Column(name = "store_name", unique=true)
private String store_name;

@JoinColumn(name="store", referencedColumnName= "store_id")
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Product> productList;
```

etc..

Here's the output: (products A should be under Butik A and products B under Butik B)

```
Butik: Butik A
Produkt: Banana A
Produkt: Morot A
Produkt: Banana B
Produkt: Apple B

Butik: Butik B
Produkt: Banana A
Produkt: Morot A
Produkt: Banana B
Produkt: Spple B
```

I have 2 additional classes, ProductDAO and StoreDAO that take care of the query, the code is similar in both classes except the table-name/class-name.

```
public class ProductDAO { 
   public static List<Product> getStoreProductsList() { 
     Session hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.getSession(); 
     hibernateSession.beginTransaction();    
     Query query = hibernateSession.createQuery("from Product");
     hibernateSession.getTransaction().commit();     
     List<Product> storeProducts = query.list(); 
     return storeProducts;   
   }
}
```

Is there any way of solving this with hibernate only?

Thanks

Comment: How do you retrieve the list of products? What do you use? load? get? Hibernate Criteria? HQL? SQL?

Comment: I have 2 additional classes, ProductDAO and StoreDAO that take care of the query, the code is similar in both classes except the table-name.     public class ProductDAO {

 public static List<Product> getStoreProductsList() {
  
  Session hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.getSession();
  hibernateSession.beginTransaction();  
  Query query = hibernateSession.createQuery("from se.kyh.stores.entities.Product");  
  hibernateSession.getTransaction().commit();  
  List<Product> storeProducts = query.list();

  return storeProducts;  
}

Comment: You should include this comment to the original question. Just try editing the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After going through your comment. It looks like you never set the condition there, of course then, you will end up getting all the products no matter which store they belong. No surprise. Where you specify the criteria?

You can do something like,

```
// One liner
List<Product> list = session.createQuery("from Product p where p.store.store_id = "
          +" :storeId").setInteger("storeId", storeId).list();
```

Or you can get the `Store` and then get the list of `Product`s like below,

```
// Another one liner
List<Product> list = session.createCriteria(Store.class)
             .add(Restrictions.eq("store_id", storeId)).list().getProductList();
```

Another and simpler way, as we know store_id is the primary key, (Thanks to [Pakore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871197/42769) for reminding me)

```
// And another. Changed to use load() instead of get() here. 
// Assuming non-existance is an error.
List<Product> list = (Store) session.load(Store.class,storeId).getProductList();
```

**[Edited]**

...to add a couple of useful pointers (Thanks to [Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604/pascal-thivent))

> [14.3 Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)
>
> [14.4 Forms of join syntax](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms)

Comment: +1 for the HQL approach. I would just add some links to the sections [14.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins) and [14.4. Forms of join syntax](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms) of the documentation.

Comment: +1 for the complete answer with the 3 ways of doing it and the credits :)

Comment: Thanks to you guys for your generosity.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your Query, it's just selecting all the products in the system, regardless of the store.

Try using hibernate criteria. It's easier to create queries for the database and you can always work from the Java "side" instead of the DB "side".

```
int storeid = 1 //whatever you want here.
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("store_id",storeid));
List<Product> list = criteria.list();
```

`list` will contain a list of the products who belong to the `Store` with `storeid` equal to the `storeid` you provide.

But for this simple query it's even **easier** if you use `session.get()` or `session.load()` (The difference between them is in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608947/hibernate-difference-between-session-get-and-session-load) or more info about them in the [documentation](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Session.html))

```
int storeid = 1; //Whatever you want
Store store = (Store) session.get(Store.class,storeid);
List<Product> list = store.getProductList();
```

As you see, Hibernate takes care of doing the join for you :).

Comment: Your 2nd snippet is good to go after a minor fix, you forgot the variable name for the `list`.  +1 for that. But your query, in first snippet, will return the list of stores not the products. So, I hope you don't mind fixing that. :)

Comment: The Criteria API being "easier" is subjective IMO. Personally I prefer HQL. And HQL is also better from a performance point of view. See [Hibernate: Criteria vs. HQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197474/hibernate-criteria-vs-hql) and [Hibernate Query vs Criteria Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784631/hibernate-query-vs-criteria-performance).

Comment: @Adeel fixed, damn mini-refactoring :D.
@Pascal well, indeed it's subjective. I think for starters and simple queries is easier to use `Criteria`, it's more Java oriented. HQL is more QL oriented. Thanks for the links though, I didn't know about the performance difference!